In-App Purchases - Is it possible to reset purchase history for TestFlight testers?
I am currently trying to add In-App purchase subscription choices (one monthly and one yearly) to my app using SubscriptionStoreView and the modifiers .onInAppPurchaseCompletion, .subscriptionStatusTask, and .manageSubscriptionsSheet. I know that I can test this via Xcode with the .storeKit configuration file.
However, I would like to know the following:

Can TestFlight testers (ie. not sandbox users) test everything?
In conjunction with #1, is it possible to reset their purchase history like we can do with sandbox users? From the doc, it sounds like that is not currently possible. What happens if testers delete the app and reinstall it from TestFlight? Does that reset the purchases?
I don't want TestFlight users to have to log out of their main AppleIds to test. Would they even have to in order to test In-App purchases? Apple doc seems to indicate that they do not.
Most of my testers will not have the ability to test by connecting to a Mac/Xcode. So, Testflight would seem to be the only option. Am I wrong? Is there a better way?

Sorry. This is all very new for me. In addition to that, there are major changes now with the new way Apple allows us to set up auto-renewing subscriptions with StoreKit 2 and the new SubscriptionStoreView and associated modifiers. So, it's very confusing imo. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.


mostly
no, TestFlight users can't clean purchase history. And this is really inconvenient. For example, if a user tested subscription with a trial, and you check trial eligibility, this user won't see trial any more.
yes, users can log in with their test account in Settings->App Store-> Sandbox account

